# Computing the Pushforward for Arbitrary Coherent Sheaves in the Context of the Segre Embedding and K-Theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Following thinking about a question from math overflow (and answering it https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4686391/299848) I was wondering about the topic:

Given the Segre embedding $\sigma: \mathbb{P}^m \times \mathbb{P}^n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^N$, where $N = mn + m + n$, I am interested in understanding the pushforward of arbitrary coherent sheaves under this embedding, especially in terms of K-theory on $\mathbb{P}^N$.

It is well-known that for line bundles, we can compute the pushforward $\sigma_* (\mathcal{O}{\mathbb{P}^m}(a) \boxtimes \mathcal{O}{\mathbb{P}^n}(b))$ and express it in terms of K-theory on $\mathbb{P}^N$. However, for arbitrary coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ on $\mathbb{P}^m$ and $\mathbb{P}^n$, respectively, I am wondering:

How can we compute the pushforward $\sigma_*(\mathcal{F} \boxtimes \mathcal{G})$ under the Segre embedding?
What is the expression for this pushforward in terms of K-theory on $\mathbb{P}^N$?
Any insights, references, or suggestions for techniques to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you know the pushforwards of line bundles, you can first decompose $F$ and $G$ in terms of line bundles (e.g., by using the Beilinson resolution), take the exterior tensor product, and then pushforward the result.